# Euclidean Algorithm Failure

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I have to prove the following statement 2 ways, one by dividers and the other by the Euclidean Algorithm.

Show that for all positive integers $a$,

$hcf(6a + 8, 4a + 5) = 1$

The first way was easy enough. Let $x = hcf(6a + 8, 4a + 5)$. By definition of $hcf$ (or $gcd$), $x$ divides both $6a + 8$ and $ 4a + 5$. It must also divide $m(6a + 8) - n(4a + 5)$ for any integers $m$ and $n$. So suppose $m=2$ and $n=-3$, we get $x|(2(6a + 8) - 3(4a + 5))$ or $x|1$, so $x$ must be $1$ (Feel free to correct if I'm wrong or missing something).

The Euclidean Algorithm was a bit more confusing at the end.

I'm just going to write out all the steps to make it clear where I'm confused:

$6a + 8= 1(4a + 5) +(2a+3)$

$4a + 5= 1(2a+3) +(2a+2)$

$2a+3= 1(2a+2) +(0a+1)$

$2a+2= 2(0a+1) +(2a+0)$

$0a+1= 0(2a+0) +(0a+1)$

So would it be enough to say that the Euclidean Algorithm never finds a $hcf$ or $gcd$ as it never reaches a remainder $0$, so it must not have any common factors greater than 1? Or would I have to use some other additional property to complete the proof after this step?

Thank you

Comment: It should stop at the step: $2a+2=(2a+2)\cdot 1+0$, because $2a+2$ is divisible by 1.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm *always* reaches the integer 0; that is the signal that the other, nonzero, integer is the GCD.

Comment: Thank you for the insight!